# WSO2 Identity Server - How to Change User Password As a Tenant Admin

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to change the password of a particular user as a tenant admin. I saw `UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl` has a function called `changeUserPassword` but this only accepts `old password` and `new password`, not `username`.

I know of the `resetUserPassword` but I do not want to use this since I want to change the password only when `oldPassword` is correctly provided.

Comment: So u mean admin need to change a user's password by providing that user's username and old password? Is this a valid use case? Do you expect the admin user to know an user's password?

Comment: Yes, it might not be a correct way to do this. I am sending all requests to WSO2 as the tenant admin instead of the user since I don't want to store/pass user's credentials. Is there a better solution that you can suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin user updating user password by sending username and old password is not a valid use case in my opinion. We can't expect admin user to know the password of a different user.

You can either use `resetUserPassword` method or otherwise you need to change password as the user himself, you need to use the `changeUserPassword` by using the cookie that user get at the login time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. We are not using basic authentication  to log in to WSO2. We are using SAML so we cannot  get the cookie from the WSO2. Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: You can use SAML2SSOAuthenticationService to get a cookie by sending the SAML response.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `UserAdmin` service `changePasswordByUser` to change the password as a user. In Identity Server 5.0.7, the web service accepts `username` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you use UserAdmin service's [1] changePasswordByUser method, still you need to provide the old password of the user. Here is the SOAP request.

```
<Envelope>
   <Header/>
   <Body>
      <changePasswordByUser>
         <userName>?</userName>
         <oldPassword>?</oldPassword>
         <newPassword>?</newPassword>
      </changePasswordByUser>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

[1] https://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin?wsdl